# Trouble with ToString and StringForm

Tags: string-manipulation, formatting

The command

```
ToString[StringForm["SomeText=`` as well as OtherText=``.", "textA", "textB"], FormatType -> InputForm]
```

produces the output

```
StringForm["SomeText=`` as well as OtherText=``.", "textA", "textB"]
```

What I would like to produce instead is

```
"SomeText=textA as well as OtherText=textB"
```

The problem, of course disappears if I remove the `FormatType->InputForm`. However I need it, because `StringForm` otherwise produces a string which consistes of multiple lines if the parameters to `StringForm` are other objects like numerical values with exponents.

I tried various combinations with `Hold` and `Evaluate`, but could not change this behaviour to what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fn[args__] :=
 Replace[
   StringForm[args],
   x : Except[_String] :> ToString[x, InputForm],
   1
 ] // ToString
```

Test:

```
fn["SomeText=`` as well as OtherText=``.", 2.0*10^(-15), 2/5]
```

> ```
> "SomeText=2.*^-15 as well as OtherText=2/5."
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
InputForm[
 ToString@StringForm["SomeText=`` as well as OtherText=``.", "textA", "textB"]]
```

> "SomeText=textA as well as OtherText=textB."

If you have version 10 you might want to try `StringTemplate`

```
StringTemplate["SomeText=`` as well as OtherText=``."]["textA", "textB"]
```

> "SomeText=textA as well as OtherText=textB."

Comment: `InputForm[
 ToString@StringForm["SomeText=`` as well as OtherText=``.", 
   2.0*10^(-15), "textB"]]` would however result in  `"              -15\nSomeText=2. 10    as well as OtherText=textB."` which is also not what I want. It should become "SomeText=2. 10^-15   as well as OtherText=textB." or similar.

Comment: @highsciguy Couldn't you use `ToString[2.0*10^(-15), InputForm]` for your arguments?

Comment: Yes, I could. However, I would need to wrap every single number in my outputs with `ToString` then.